# HTML <select> one name for multiple $_POST variables

Tags: html, select, names

What I'm trying to do is to use one select element to get two `$_POST` variables with the same value.
For example:

```
<select name='a1'>
  <option value='1'>one</option>
  <option value='2'>two</option>
  <option value='3'>three</option>
</select>
```

will result in `$_POST[a1] => 1`

what I would like to do is something like this:

```
<select name='a1, a2'>
  <option value='1'>one</option>
  <option value='2'>two</option>
  <option value='3'>three</option>
</select>
```

So:

```
$_POST[a1] => 1, $_POST[a2] => 1
```

or

```
$_POST[a1] => 2, $_POST[a2] => 2
```

whatever the selection might be by the form user.

Comment: Could you attach the code you are using that is actually performing these actions?

Comment: Please provide a snippet of your use-case so we can understand better. Is there a reason why you're against just cloning the variable in the back-end?

Comment: I can do it in the back end, but not sure how to approach it on the front end

Comment: in front end you can create a hidden field with desired name and assign the value of SELECT to it onChange

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I also think so.

Comment: Thanks Ali I will try it, just needed a point to start, formulate it as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid an explicit script block (also avoiding jquery dependency), use the following shorthand:

```html
<!--this should be hidden, set to text Just for preview-->
<input type="text" name="a2" value="1">

<select name="a1" onchange="document.getElementsByName('a2')[0].value=this.value">
<option value='1'>one</option>
<option value='2'>two</option>
<option value='3'>three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `input type="hidden"` to your form and then use it to store the variable based on the current value of your select field.

```
// Add this hidden input to your form
<input type="hidden" name="a2" value=""></input>

// Use this script to change it's value based on selection from "a1"
$("select[name=a1]").change(
    function(){ 
        $("input[name=a2]").val($(this).val()); 
    }
);
```